# windows won't boot anymore

Tags: windows, data-loss-prevention

I was have windows 8 beside Ubuntu in dial boot and I decided to install Windows7 and I was in rush and didn't have flash drive then I installed it with windows 8 running together, after I finished the installation and booted to WIN7 I decided to delete the WIN8's partition I installed mini tool partition and rebooted and deleted the partition.. :( the next was it won't boot again into windows :( I thought windows only damaged, the next day I got from friend a flash drive with windows xp inside it and installed Windows xp then all of my files and partitions  Except WINxp partition are damaged... :( I was able to recover some files but the important is gone :(  I just want to know what happend exactly????

Comment: You mention several generic things you did without describing any details of how you did them or exactly what the symptoms are.  People can only guess at what might have happened.

Comment: @fixer1234 i am sorry for not being describing details, I've found the reasons that leaded to the problem, after hours of searching on google i found that the MBR is damaged when i deleted the first partition on the hard disk (WIN 8). I've learned from this critical mistake, sadly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different hard disk or computer to boot and connect this disk as a secondary.

Use active partition recovery or such other partition recovery software to recover all your deleted partitions.

If you want to do it on your own computer, then make a partition where your win7 partition was, install windows and boot into it, then try to recover your partitions using a recovery software.

Comment: I've found the reasons that leaded to the problem, after hours of searching on google i found that the MBR is damaged when i deleted the first partition on the hard disk (WIN 8). I've learned from this critical mistake, sadly :(